# How create target for imported library with cmake

Tags: cmake

In my project I ship a compiled static library foo.lib I want to link to from my main.cpp executable. I want to import the compiled library as an IMPORTED library.

File structure:

```
external/foo/lib/foo.lib
external/foo/include/foo.h
external/CMakeLists.txt
src/CMakeLists.txt
src/main.cpp
CMakeList.txt
```

```
external/CMakeLists.txt:

add_library(foolib STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(foolib PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/foo/lib/"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/foo/include/"
)
```

Currently when I try to compile I get the error:

```
could not open '../../../external/foo/lib/': no such file or directory
```

so maybe using `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}` is not the correct approach.

- What cmake variable should I use to define the path of the library?
- Is this approach correct, or should I write a FindFoo.cmake module to locate this library (even if within my project)?
- Can I use `target_include_directories` instead of setting `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` directly?

Comment: Please see the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550334/3987854) for linking external libraries as CMake imported targets. The `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property must contain the **full path** to the library, including the library name.

Comment: Right! Adding the full path to the .lib file allows me linking against it correctly indeed.